# Unable to scrape csrf token (available in page source) from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape csrf token from a website. However, the script that I created fails miserably even when the very token is available in page source. This is the [site url](https://fanniemae.mbs-securities.com/fannie/search?issrSpclSecuType=Super&status=Active).

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://fanniemae.mbs-securities.com/fannie/search?issrSpclSecuType=Super&status=Active'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    csrf = soup.select_one("[name='_csrf']").get("content")
    print(csrf)
```

> How can I scrape csrf token from that site using requests?

Comment: Does `r.text` match what you expect?

Comment: So what is the output of `print(csrf)`?

Comment: When I tested your code, I received a 'status code 500'. Have you been able to obtain a 'status code 200' for this url request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to include `Accept` key and value within headers to get the required response. This is how I fetch tabular content from that site using requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://fanniemae.mbs-securities.com/fannie/search?issrSpclSecuType=Super&status=Active'
link = 'https://fanniemae.mbs-securities.com/api/search/fannie'
params = {
    'issrSpclSecuType': 'Super',
    'status': 'Active',
    'page': 1,
    'max_results': 100,
    'sortField': 'cusip',
    'sortAsc': 'true'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['Accept'] = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    s.headers['x-csrf-token'] = soup.select_one("[name='_csrf']")["content"]
    s.headers['referer'] = 'https://fanniemae.mbs-securities.com/fannie/search?issrSpclSecuType=Super&status=Active'
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    for item in res.json():
        print(item['cusip'])
```